# "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" error in my telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, telegram-bot, telepot

My Telegram bot code was working fine for weeks and I didn't changed anything today suddenly I got `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]` error and my bot code no longer working in my PC.
I use Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm usng telepot library.

What is wrong and how to fix it?

**Edit:** I'm using getMe method and I don't know where is the certificate and how to renew it and I didn't import `requests` in my bot code. I'm using telepot API by importing `telepot` in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your certificate expired, that is why it worked fine earlier. Just renew it and all should be good. If you're using `requests` under the hood you can just pass `verify=False` to the `post` or `get` method but that is unwise.

The renew procedure depends on from where do you get your certificate. If your using letsencrypt for example with certbot. Issuing `sudo certbot renew` command from shell will suffice.

Comment: I'm using getMe method and I don't know where is the certificate and how to renew it and I didn't import `requests` in my bot code. I'm using `telepot` API by importing `telepot` in my code.

Comment: @man The certificate is located on your server, the renew method varies as my answer states.